# Why Have I Been Banned?-Better Question

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Recently I posted a question, that has given me no answer. I accept that I have not given all details and I am going to attempt the question again for the last time.

Please note that I have read the famous post about getting banned, which how can I not if it shows up when I try to ask a question. This famous question is:  http://goo.gl/C1Kwu

Even though I have read this, I see no reason for me to get banned, and it appears very much like an error, even though I doubt it. The reasons for this are:

1. I have very little downvotes on my questions, in fact only one, which has been added after I got banned, probably because someone has looked at my previous 'what did I do wrong?' post. I have probably 2/5 of my questions not voted (which I have deleted 3 post that weren't voted), but is this enough to get banned?
2. On my answer side, I have only -3 points for one of my answers (which I deleted), which was a stupid mistake I made in reading the question. The other answers I have made are half not voted, and half voted.
3. Most of my questions now have been ticked if there is an answer, and the answers that aren't ticked are answers that have no meaning, or does not work at all. I could tick the answers just to get points, but I believe that's not the stack overflow spirit.

When I got banned, it was actually a day after I had used Stack Overflow, and at least 52 minutes before asking another question, so it was not instant.

Is there anything I have missed? I have read the ban post, and it states that 'deleting posts counts to a ban' but all post that have been deleted were deleted after the ban was committed, also it says that unvoted counts towards a ban, but the amount of unvoted is between 2/5 of my posts. It also says to fix up your questions made, which I have done, but still no removal.

If anyone has a reason to the ban I will happily appreciate it.

Comment: The details of the banning script are not public, so any answer you'll get will be based speculation. Moderators can see what has been deleted, so they will have some more detailed info on which to base their answer, but it'll be speculation nonetheless.

Comment: How are we suppose to learn what we have done, if we don't even know what we have done? Why isn't it public?

Comment: Because that'll give less well-meaning users the power to bypass it.

Comment: and by bypassing it, your not doing it anymore, and by not doing it anymore, you are a better user.

Comment: No, by bypassing we mean "knowing exactly what amount of crap you can get away with". They want to prevent that from happening.

Comment: With regards to your ban. 3 out of 12 have been closed. 1 migrated (though I'm not sure if that counts) and you say only 1 has been deleted? You're lacking upvotes, but all taken into account, you can't be in very deep. Unless there's other content I can't see.

Comment: What low would want to get away with stuff on these websites? Its fun to spam questions and answers? Not for me anyway

Comment: To Bart, everything I have said is right, nothing else, otherwise I would have stuffed up this question too.

Comment: Then, if you can't improve the content present, all that remains is to answer questions or edit content to gain rep. I would guess it should not take a whole lot of effort to get yourself out of the ban.

Comment: *"at least 52 minutes before asking another question"*... How do you know?

Comment: There is nothing much that can be added to what already said in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really cannot post questions anymore you should:

- Avoid deleting too much and too often: too much deletion grants a ban. You should try to improve your existing questions, where possible.
- Provide more good quality answers. You currently have 3 answers where one has an upvote, another one is accepted at 0 points and another one is simply at 0. Providing more good quality content will help you lift the ban.
- You might have deleted answers but I cannot see them: in such a case, you could try fixing them and undeleting them, or flagging them for moderator attention if a mod deleted them.

This will certainly help you. Gain enough reputation and your ban will be lifted.

In order to undelete a post, go to your answer. In the lower left part of the post you'll see something like this:

[image: undeleting]

Click **undelete** and it should undelete. In case the post was deleted by a moderator, you can only flag it for moderator attention **after** you fixed the post.

Comment: Thankyou for the comment, I wont tick the box until this ban is uplifted for obvious reasons. How do you undelete posts?

Comment: @tristo Check my edit.

Comment: awesome thanks for the comment

Comment: You cannot undelete a question like that (once you navigated away from the page). There are [other means](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101361/how-do-i-undelete-my-question) though.

Comment: @Arjan You're right. I shall fix it.

Answer (score 8):

You are incorrect in the number of deleted and downvoted questions that you have. You actually had five deleted questions, three of which you deleted yourself. Two of the deleted questions had been downvoted heavily, one of them six times and the other four.

For reference, these were the deleted questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118398/decompile-launcher-dll
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339064/ajax-better-in-dreamweaver-or-visual-web-developer
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826024/how-to-upload-webpart-programmatically
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496281/redirect-url-different-for-different-roles
- [Dreamweaver running google instead of my .aspx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355620/dreamweaver-running-google-instead-of-my-aspx-file)

I've gone ahead and undeleted the last three of these that you deleted yourself, to give you a chance to edit them into shape.

Given that you have a total of four downvoted questions, two of them heavily, and had five deleted questions, it's easy to see how the question quality safeguards kicked in here. With me undeleting three of your self-deleted questions, that should help with some of this, but you're going to need to learn from the downvoted questions and improve your existing ones so that they are better received in the future.

Comment: I forgot about them