# Does undeleting a question reverse the deleted posts count?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, post-ban, undelete

With reference to post bans, and one of the reason being deleted posts.

If a user undeletes posts, does this reverse the count on deleted posts?

Comment: You'll find numerous instances where mods have undeleted posts to help users out of bans (this allows the banned user to edit the posts into shape). Since the specifics of the ban algorithm aren't public, that's the best you'll get.

Comment: Yes. For more read [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/187824) and it's detailed answer

Comment: @Mat I was not attempting to get the algorithms! Just wanted to know, as I have deleted a lot of posts thanks for the answer.

Comment: @hims056 yes I have seen that link, but it doesn't actually answer this specific question

Comment: You can only undelete posts you yourself deleted. If your post was deleted by someone else then you need a moderator's help.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards yep, just wanted to know if it a good thing for me to undelete and modify my posts or if once the damage is done (by deleting) then the damage is done

Comment: @Yve: see my previous comment, and e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146374/158667 - as I said, you probably won't get a firm answer on this

Comment: @Mat yes this new link answers it completely, this question is a duplicate.. best I just flag it and walk away? Actually the question is not a duplicate, but the answer to that question does answer it, however searching for the answer to this was not so easy

Comment: Flag what and what for?

Comment: Oh my question here lol, I thought it was a duplicate, but, technically it is not, although the answer to the other question answers it. Is it a good idea for you to post that answer (the ones in your comments here) and at least people can search this and will find the answer more easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is *possible* that undeleting some of your deleted questions will shift things enough to lift a question ban.  However, that's likely to leave you right on the edge of being banned again.  It's a good idea to go the extra mile and improve any questions you undelete (or ask a moderator to undelete) so that they don't get even more downvotes and cause the ban to kick in again.

Comment: oh yeh! I meant with a view to editing them, should I put that in my question here or just leave it? thnx for that Bill

Comment: @Yve I think it's alright the way it is.  Undeleting and improving questions is the prescribed method for lifting a ban, so it's natural to wonder if *just* undeleting questions is enough.  It can be if you have enough questions that you can undelete, but that will probably only work temporarily.

Comment: @Yve You probably shouldn't leave your question in [this state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376857/under-construction-being-modfied) for much longer. Also I don't know how [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377519/unable-to-install-script-on-chrome-to-be-modified) can be edited to be a fit for StackOverflow, unless you change it to a completely different question, which would be an odd thing to do. I guess not every question is fit for undeletion...

Comment: Yes, I deleted too many things, in a spring cleaning attempt! which I now know is a very bad idea. I don't have most of my deleted answers bookmarked, do you know another way of finding them..I've looked here, but it doesn't look hopeful http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted

Comment: So what do I do about a question that is not fit for rehabilitation? I guess that's the challenge, to figure out how to make it so

Comment: @Yve Since that question has no answers that would be invalidated by changing it, you are free to completely edit it to a different question and ask for it to be reopened.  This is only allowed on questions with zero answers.

Comment: @BilltheLizard so I can completely change the topic??? that would be great.. hey I appreciate all your time, I'm not a vampire, just very thorough and a bit crazy (sorry about the crazy bit), I thank you all for tolerating me.

Comment: @Yve Sure, if there are no answers and it's closed/deleted anyway, why not?  We want people to remove bad questions and ask good ones, so this is win/win.

Comment: This is so good to know. We should post this particular issue as a question. Shall I?

Comment: @Yve It was asked a few months ago. [What should be done with a closed question that has been completely rewritten?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165203/1288)  See [Shog9's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165199/what-should-be-done-with-a-closed-question-that-has-been-completely-rewritten#comment482215_165201) in particular.

Comment: Thnx Bill, perfecto! I'd much prefer to revamp them, than just delete.