# Editing answers

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

If I've answered a question, then from seeing another users answer, I realise, my answer is wrong. Is it ok to edit my answer, based on this new awareness from another answer, that my answer is wrong?

Comment: Hey thnx Meta users, I edited my answer and acknowledged and thanked the other user (already had given him an upvote) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only acceptable to edit your answer to be correct, but it is encouraged.

However, if you came to this realization from another user's answer or work, it is considered polite to give them credit for it (also the fact that everything on SO is under a CC license)

Comment: ...or just delete your answer.

Comment: @DannyBeckett That too. But sometimes, I'll keep mine around if I have something more to add.

Comment: @DannyBeckett deleting the answer is not a good idea, excessive deleted posts can leave to a post ban http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186652/does-undeleting-a-question-reverse-the-deleted-posts-count

Comment: @Yve I wouldn't be too paranoid about that. I've deleted answers where this has happened before, and have never been banned.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I went through a spring clean on my account and was deleting post I thought were poor! lol so I am mindful now.

Comment: @Yve Two options in my opinion: if you can still make your answer to add something that does not exist in other answers then yes, edit it to make it correct. Otherwise if by editing you effectively making it same answer as the other one delete it and upvote that other answer. Otherwise (if you keep the answer edited to make it look like the other answer) you risk justified downvotes due to copying other answer, not to mention it's very rude.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes good advice, if you could pls post his an an answer.. yes I edited my answer, but my explanation of the process was different http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387642/correct-way-to-use-session/17387673#17387673

Comment: @Yve this answer sums up what I said, it won't be fair to add similar answer. :)

Comment: ok I'll mark this as answer :) (man I don't mean to be thick, I can be intelligent, but am seriously retarded in some things.. you should see me manage my social relationships !!! like really badly hahahahaha)