# How to recover from poor reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, post-ban

I now know the error of my ways and the stack overflow community has shunned my ability to ask a question but I am on my way to recovery. How do you suggest I bounce back?
I have a question that I really need answered but I can't post and I can truly say that I regret having asked a few of my questions which were unclear.

Comment: Minimum reputation is 1. It never goes below that. If you can't ask a question, it is not a reflection of your reputation (other with 1 rep can ask question), but of how your past questions have been received by the community.

Comment: As @Ral commented - you got a message when trying to post your question. That message had a link. Did you follow the link? Did you read the contents? It explains how to recover.

Comment: I did and I've edited my own previously voted down questions and tried to answer a few of other users questions that were moderately easy to answer.However, I've reached a total of 7 reputation points on the Stack-overflow site but I still cannot post questions.

Comment: You are on the right track - though none of your answers got any upvotes. I suggest you look at them, compare them to the answers that did get upvotes and learn how to do better. Same with your questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186652/does-undeleting-a-question-reverse-the-deleted-posts-count this addresses your issue

Comment: I gave you an upvote, as you  seem to have identified your problem and are trying to effect a change

Comment: what is your question? I will help you post it, if it has merit

Comment: @Delrog go and see this question, I made an edit for you, not changing the question's meaning, just making your meaning clear.. maybe you can flag to reopen it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444171/i-want-to-allow-a-user-to-add-an-image-and-text-to-my-website-and-for-it-to-rema

Comment: @Delrog I suggest you take a step back. I get the impression you are asking questions that are a bit beyond your reach.. perhaps when you are thinking of posting a question, you can perhaps think to yourself, How can I make this into two questions and then just post the first question.. Just try for one question at a time.. and perhaps go back and go over some of your programming fundamentals with html, js, php .. get a good grounding in html and css before trying to code too much in php and js.. is you don't know where html/css limits are, you will be fumbling with when to use php/js

Comment: +1 good on you for asking for ways to improve and accepting your past failings and seeking advice to improve.  I have no doubt, with your positive attitude, that you'll get there.

Answer (score 9):

The way to recover from poor reputation is :

- **To understand why you have the low reputation.**

> I have a question that I really need answer but I can't post and I can
>   truly say that I regret having asked a few of my questions which were
>   unclear

- **Take steps to have post ban removed:**

[Improve your downvoted or closed posts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186652/does-undeleting-a-question-reverse-the-deleted-posts-count)

- **Take step to build up your reputation with positive contribution on
  the site.**

[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

> - Search and research
> - Be on topic
> - Be specific
> - Make it relevant to    others
> - Keep an open mind

[How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

By participating in suggested edits to improve posts, will also give you [reputation bonuses](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score -13):

**This advice is for new users only.**

They say you have contribute to the site (difficult for you and I.)  Maybe **grab answers from other sites for questions here.**  This will work, if you pick good answers you will get votes.  **Be sure to credit your sources, it is very important.**  How else are you ever going to gain enough credit to get back on with your limited experience?

*MY EXPERIENCE:*

In my own case I asked a total of four questions, one of which was kind of dumb. I asked very clear questions that sadly did not require sample code.  There were two that require expertise.  Yes, they were programming related.  Instead of getting **just** answers from someone that knows the specific issue or has the same problem, I got voted down from people that don't, or so it seemed.  **The fault is entirely mine for not understanding the site, in your case, as a coding newbie, it is unfair.**  The site doesn't want to exclude new programmers, it is policy issue evolving around Q&A type site standards and not wasting too much time where the answer people are concerned.

**Ignore negative votes on this answer** or discussion among the experts on other posts.  They are not in your position of being new and having already made too many mistakes. Trust me on this...

1) There is also naturally a difference between the stated and debated guidelines for questions and what actually occurs on the site that has to do with psychology.
 2) Remember that you might not only get negative votes for questions that have no clear answer, but also for questions where the answer is unknown (to the reader), 
 3) or it annoys the reader on some level.  Its not malicious, its just human nature.
 4) Someone else will probably come to your defense if that happens, but that won't help you.

*CLEAR ADVICE FOR THE FUTURE:*

This is not a rant, listen carefully... Yes, **read their page about what question to ask and how.**  Your in trouble, so read everything you can find.  Read a variety of questions and answers to get a feel for things.  Beyond that:

5) Only ask about bugs or language features.
 6) When you do, provide examples or ALL the code.
 7) Before posting, research the issue and provide details.
 8) If the answer really isn't here already, get you answer somewhere else more tolerant until you have some points.
 9) If the answer doesn't involve someone pointing to a bug in your code, don't ask at all.

Remember, you start with no points, you can get blocked very easily, and negative votes aren't necessarily tied to the rules an guidelines.  Remember down votes can be about any flaw in your question.  The site members likely do not want to block you, they probably do not know they are.

*AS YOUR SKILLS ADVANCE A BIT:*

If you are about to be blocked, this is not a site for getting expert answers to complex programming problems.

1) **This is a site where EXPERTS** mainly address simple coding problems.  That is not really true, but is true where down votes are concerned.
 2) Even then, never ask a question that is too advanced even if it is specific and clearly stated, especially if it COULD evoke discussion.  You might not know when you are making a mistake.
 3) If your question could in any way be interpreted as asking for a list or a poll, do not ask.  For example, avoid expressions like "Has anyone had this problem?"  You might be asking if something is a bug or not but that be considered doing a poll.

4) Perhaps your questions are being marked duplicate.
 i) Reread the guidelines,
 ii) Do not just use the list of existing answers that appears when you type the title to your question.  The answer is probably somewhere, go to the search page.
 iii) However, there are many issues with the search page and you need to use it right to first narrow the list of available answers.

Although a work in progress, there is a work around to avoid the search page issues, see [I'm having problems finding answers and my posts are getting marked duplicate, what do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189892/im-having-problems-finding-answers-and-my-posts-are-getting-marked-duplicate-w) Bugs in the search page can cause you to not find an answer, resulting in down votes.

*CONCLUSION:*

This sounds like quite a slam of Stack Overflow but it's not really.  **It would be trivial were it not for the automatic blocking mechanism**.  I do appreciate the help I've gotten and like the site but there are lots of other good sites out there. Did you look for your answer in other sites before asking here?

*(edit)* Very reluctantly, I would have to say **your best option is to create a different account even with a different email** and hope the two accounts are not merged later.  **Warning, this might NOT be allowed, I've seen conflicting advice on the site.**  Do not "sock puppet" (Up vote your other account) as this will really harm your reputation when you are eventually discovered.  You are allowed to add an account, usually for security reasons.  Your legitimate, right?  Nothing malicious or illegal, correct?  If you get blocked again then the problem is probably on your end. If you just want to ask a question there is little harm.*(end edit)*

Otherwise, come here when you see the answer in Google and posted it (cited), accept you can no longer ask questions here and when you eventually can contribute, if you are truly offended, do that somewhere else.  As they say, vote with your feet.  You can ask questions anywhere and still use this resource.  On the other hand, we all get lots of help along the way, so rather than blaming the site users for an **automated** blocking mechanism, take it in stride and contribute here also (be mature.)  I try to give more than I get if I can.

**Update:**
This being my first comment on the meta site (now at -2) it will take very little time before I'm blocked from this site too.  **Again, this is not a rant, it is really sound advice.**  I.E. not only was I not upset, I've just spent a day contributing the site.

Decide for yourself though,  I asked a very straight forward question that could have a very expert level answer:

[Does object literal notation result if faster executing code or is it slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653474/does-object-literal-notation-containing-functions-execute-faster-than-plain-func)

(I hate saying this) The best answer I got was amounted to find out for yourself at jsperf.  Looks like an absolutely great tool, I appreciate that and gave the answer a vote.  I was happy to add lots of spurious detail when asked.  I did not get an answer (which is perfectly OK.)  But the issue is I am getting more and more negative points on top of the original vote downs.  Later on, I learned it was a duplicate question I had missed because of the issues on the search page.

By asking two questions that nobody answered, and one dumb one, I'm blocked.  I've read two different articles on this site and a few posts like this as well as the help.  I have to conclude that at no point did do thing incorrectly, except to keep adding detail.  I also phrased the question avoiding the use of technical terms involving scope.  Scope is different in compiled and interpreted languages and JavaScript has some complex scope features.  This could (fairly) be considered badly worded.  So bad (simple) wording, duplicate questions, too little detail, too much detail.  Any of these things could result in a down vote.  See the point?  Your blocked, it matters to you.

Other things that might be at issue:
(I don't mean you specifically but:) You are used to forums, new to Q&A or familiar with neither.  You are too verbose.  You are mixing two issues in one question.  You can't distinguish being detailed from getting into discussion.  You are too impatient or maybe rude.  You really haven't read all the help.  You haven't found or checked out the meta stack overflow site.

**So exactly what would your advice be to a new or possibly inexperienced member be?**  The above is great advice if you are already in trouble.  Follow it.  If it's bad advice,  I'd welcome feedback on the problem with my own four questions.  I expect many site users to disagree but... for example, what in this specif post warrants blocking me from asking further questions or making more posts.  I gave a newbie the best answer they could get at the top despite it's going against stated guidelines. (-6 and counting)

The point is, you will get repetitive advice about reading the site documentation

Comment: *"Maybe grab answers from other sites for questions here"* No, ***do not do this***! This will *not* "work". Plagarism is not acceptable. Your answers will get flagged and deleted. If you do find something else on the Internet that you would like to include in an answer, you *absolutely must* give credit back to the original source. [Attribution is absolutely required here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). You can do this with a link, and by setting the original text off as a block quote.

Comment: I won't downvote (if you were one of the high rep users here I would).. there are many points here that I really don't agree with. You don't need to post code, some questions are not aided by posting code, in the OPs case here, he should make efforts to show some code.. in html.css.php,jquery questions, he needs to show effort, now as for difficult programming problems, I also take issue, as long as a "piece" of a programming problem can be addressed on SO there is a wealth of experience and talent to answer. And there are other forums.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I agree, there is much I take issue with here, But I am trying to encourage dHorse to come back to SO and have a better experience.. Now I have brawled with you Cody, Bart, Dragon Breath, Unicorn Fairy Dust, Minitech,, Hell I dobbed on Minitech to himself!! there is room for us all to express ourselves and grow and the community is a great leveller to let us know if we are getting hotter or colder

Comment: And Dhorse, before you go runnng off, take a look at my posts on this site and the votes and comments. If I can come back for more aftr stomping off here, on a semi regular basis, you can come back from this

Comment: I'll admit that I didn't read past that first line to the rest of the answer. I don't really understand what DHorse is ranting about here. The observation that it's an experts-only site is *utterly wrong*. Questions and users of all skill levels are welcome here. We do have high standards for questions, but those standards are all set out in the FAQ, which is pretty typical for online resources. And as for the last paragraph—there are *lots* of links to SO questions on Google. And you certainly *can* ask questions here. Sorry you had a bad experience.

Comment: @CodyGray I have just been involved in the same debate here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189485/are-questions-about-implementation-details-of-third-party-libraries-allowed

Comment: @CodyGray Yes and I should have mentioned that.  I always quote the site and user.  It is only fair.

Comment: @Yve I agree the talent is there, and my experience is very limited here.  Look at my questions, most of the detail I added is a negative, not a positive.  By simply asking if the object literal style runs faster I am now blocked.  I'll gladly take criticism on my own usage of the site but my answer accurately reflects my experience here.

I really like this site, but the only questions I have are of the sort I posted and I am so far convinced they will get a lot of down votes.  But of course I can't ask any more.  It's OK, I knew this would happen before asking the last question.

Comment: @CodyGray This is a site with a lot of experts and great for people learning coding.  It's clearly not safe to ask the questions I did.  I think it is save to ask questions specific to a chunk of code or one directed at language syntax.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm getting in more trouble with limited space.  Beginner questions always have an answer on line, usually here.  Same with intermediate ones (without duplicating it here.)

Comment: Re "voting with your feet." I did not mean offense but in general, quid pro quo applies.  I contributed a lot elsewhere without that expectation though.  I don't here because my opinions and expertise with HTML and JavaScript are of limited value (compared to the available experts.)  Once a newbie is kicked off it will be years before they can earn their way back on.  Its newbies and people with language issues that are going to get blocked.  Maybe some lazy people too.  If they want back on, that leaves (properly attributed) quotes from other sites and not much else.

Comment: @Yve I've read the "third-party libraries allowed?" and the referenced "Single()" topic and they were fascinating.  It appears that discussion is pretty lively on meta.SO.  One really relevant tip that I overlooked is do not ask questions too far beyond your level of expertise.

Comment: @DHorse yes, it's not for the feint hearted and I can be my own worst enemy.. just keep plodding, we have all been new and man, the site if pedantic, good, bad, or neither.. but programming is pedantic, and it does work, not perfect, but works SO I mean,, .. as for Meta, I find it entertaining and exasperating at times too

Comment: You are getting downvotes because your answer is in direct opposition to the stated site goals and rules. "_Ignore any comments and negative votes you see about this answer_" That's terrible advice. The comments and negative votes _mean_ something. People should learn what they mean and benefit from them. "_...get negative votes for...questions where the answer is unknown (to them), or it annoys the reader on some level._" Please provide evidence to support that statement. (cont'd)

Comment: "_Only ask about bugs or language features_" No, feel free to ask about _all_ of the things described in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). "_especially if it COULD evoke discussion, even if you say 'I would like a simple list,'_" Discussion and requests for lists are explicitly [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). "_If the answer doesn't involve someone pointing to a bug in your code, don't ask at all._" Again, don't limit yourself in this way. Be sure to read the on-topic documentation and ask accordingly.

Comment: I was unaware of that requests for lists (say of obfuscators) was not allowed.  Thank you.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins re:"direct opposition to the stated site goals and rules" that is my very point.  Despite trying and I feel meeting those requirements you can still get blocked.  The post is the best explanation I can come up with.

Comment: If you feel that you have been blocked when using the site in accordance with the rules, I encourage you to post a Meta question specifically about that incident. The feedback may help you to understand where you went wrong, or (if the block was incorrect) it will be corrected.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins re:"post a Meta question specifically about that incident." That's great. I did not want to further abuse the site or appear to rant but some feedback would be great.  The real problem has been I don't understand the nuances no matter how clear the articles.

Comment: @DHorse, I have to say your linked question is *not* expert level, and people did *not* downvote it because it was over their heads.  It is a huge wall of words that uses many hundreds of words to ask a fourteen-word question ("Does using object literal notation to create objects have any effect on their performance?") The recent comment by Lightness Races in Orbit nails it: it makes no difference at all.  If you ask concise, clear questions, you'll get upvotes and answers. If you ramble on like this, you'll get downvotes and closure.

Comment: @DHorse Just make it clear that you're *asking* what you've done that isn't in accordance with the site's guidelines and how you can fix it, rather than complaining about the fact that the site's guidelines aren't what you want them to be (which is pretty much what this post is).  You complaining about not liking the guidelines isn't worth posting about.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I couldn't agree more about "huge wall of words that uses many hundreds of words to ask a fourteen-word question."  My questions start off very brief and in response to requests for code and down votes I add detail despite it being irrelevant.  I also feel the clarifications regarding naming conventions and types of object to be spurious.  In fact, nothing more than the subject line should have be required.  I'll restore the post to it's original.  Thank you.

Comment: @Servy Yes I've never done a post like this before because I agree.  It would be nice if someone reworded the whole thing as it just keeps getting longer and longer and sounds even more like a complaint.  The only real complaint was about the behavior of automatic blocking.  Per George Cummins comments, no matter how brief or long I seem to get negative votes on those questions that were quite appropriate. That is good feedback were I not blocked.

Comment: I was interested in tracking the reaction to the post.  At this time it is at -9.  In my own posts, how does the most basic question done per George Cummins advice get negative votes?  In my experience, some people want more detail, some people want less.  That seems to result in negative votes, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: In another post, I reported pseudo random JS error occuring in IE8 on comment lines.  Posting 10K lines of script was out of the question but I did supply snap shots and a link upon request. It wasn't great but hardly reason to block a new user or even vote it down.  I merely wanted to know if others had the problem (1 person.)    Was it unsolvable?  Not believable?  Too difficult?  Who knows but the real problem is the automatic blocking.

Comment: @DHorse: Meta posts have a higher threshold for banning, due to the propensity of downvotes on Meta.  But even on Stack Overflow a single negatively-voted post wouldn't get you banned.  Users have to fail repeatedly and hard to get banned.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well being new to the site I had four questions with about -6 or -7 overall (it's changing so I am not sure.  It was something like -4, -2, -3)  The formula is not disclosed.  Brief or detailed, object literal notation ended in a -3.  I was directed to an post from this thread that referenced a similar thread about a CLR question.  I have read extensive questions and explanations of the performance impact of CLR (C#).  Pretty straight forward, it was a question someone can either answer or they can't.  Anyway, that was the third and final strike when starting from zero.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill My apologies, I am now told that the only reason my object literal notation question was unblocked was because I added all the detail.  Although you rightly considered the detail ridiculous others rightly felt the question was vague in it's original form.  I think that more than makes my point.  If you are new and have no reputation, follow my additional guidelines above.  100 negative votes won't change that reality.

Comment: I notice that in the case of the object literal notation you might also note that the one good answer basically said that objects are objects and OLN is merely an issue of style.  The question was about regular functions vs OLN.  Similarly in this thread, I in no way implied this was an experts only site, I said if you are new select your questions carefully or you will get auto-blocked whether they are valid or not.  I have no issue with negative voters per se.  Perhaps not knowing the correct term for functions not contained in objects was the problem.  Dunno.

Comment: No, do not create another account to circumvent a question ban. You are not the first person to have thought of this, and many who have tried this have been caught.

Comment: Thanks, you've given me a *great* tutorial for being IP-banned!

Comment: @Doorknob I hope I follow you but I am not sure if dynamic IP addresses get around that, say by doing a reset IP.  There is that private browsing service too.  So IP banning is one tool.

Comment: Is there a policy on this site concerning developers having a duplicate ID so they can hide questions that relate to their software project?  Tech's can certainly get in hot water using a site where non-disclosure is concerned.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: this is *terrible* advice and most of it is wrong.

Comment: Point clarified.  But... beyond the advice outlined in the various SO articles... what would you recommend the new user additionally do?  No rep, little programming knowledge, what do you do?

Comment: And that was the point.   I am (still) waiting for a single suggestion that goes beyond the site guidelines.  Sage advice and all that.