# Where can I ask questions about behind-the-scenes details?

Tags: support, asking-questions, site-recommendation, scope

Where can I ask questions related to programming logic and what is really happening behind the scenes.

For example: the jQuery `.focus()` method is supposed to work with form elements only, but its even working with div tags. I want to know how this is possible, and what the logic behind this is.

Would these types of questions be appropriate for Stack Overflow? Or is there another site where I should ask?

Comment: Related discussion: [Are questions about implementation details of third-party libraries allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189485)

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is a good place to ask that. According to their own [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) you should ask about:

- Specific programming problems
- Software algorithms
- Coding techniques
- Software development tools

That looks like an specific programming problem to me. Also if you're not sure how to, check [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) how to write a good question!

Golden rules I always try to follow:

- Always try to add some code or at least a description what you have tried. In this case a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what's happening would be great.
- Focus on your problem. What did you do? What did you expect to happen?  What's happening instead?
- Avoid greetings and abbreviations. Sentences like "gr8! thx rly u rock! lolz :)." are not welcome.
- Tag it properly. In most cases you won't need to ask "How to do something `using jquery`? You ask `How to do something?` and add the JQuery tag.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow would be the appropriate place for these types of questions, as long as they meet [our general guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Essentially, the question must:

- describe the problem in detail
- be reasonably scoped
- (ideally) provide a simple, self-contained example that reproduces the problem/situation described

As long as you ask an *actual question* (e.g., "Why does *x* do *y* in the case of *z*?"), you're perfectly fine.

Comment: so is the above question fit to be asked on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes, it would be fine. That's the whole point of my answer. And to give you some tips on how to ask it.